# How to set position of image on right top side of divs of screen?

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML along with Django to create a web application. I need to place my div on the right side of the screen. It is doing that, but it is below the rest of the widgets. This is what it looks like:

[image]

The place I circled is where the div is, but it needs to be on the right at the top.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="dark">
    <head>
        <title>{{object.destination}} in {{trip_length}} days</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}"/>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body id="bg" style="margin:0px">
        {% block content %}
            <div style="background-color: white; height: 100%; padding: 2%;">
                <h1 class="mt-2">{{object.destination}} in {{trip_length}} days</h1>
                <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">
                
                <div style="width: 48%; background-color: white; padding: 2%; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; border-radius: 3px;">
                    <h3 class="mt-3">Find Places</h3>
                    <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">

                    <form method="post" novalidate>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ find_places_form|crispyA }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">Find Places</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div style="width: 48%; background-color: white; padding: 2%; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; border-radius: 3px; margin-top: 2%;">
                    <h3 class="mt-3">Find Hotels</h3>
                    <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">

                    <form method="post" novalidate>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ find_hotels_form|crispy }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">Find Hotels</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                {% if place_results_name %}
                    <div style="height: 75vh; width: 48%; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; border-radius: 3px; float:right">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; padding: 2%; margin: 1%;">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'images/pexels-photo-10768835.jpeg'%}" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{place_results_name}}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Place description...</p>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Add to Trip</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here it is responsive design (col-md is used) so, open in full screen to see :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between">
        <!-- left side -->
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="row border">
            <form class="p-4 mb-4">
              <h2>Find Places</h2>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" />
              <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2">find place</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!--  -->
          <br />
          <!--  -->
          <div class="row border">
            <form class="p-4 mt-4">
              <h2>Find Places</h2>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" />
              <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2">find place</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- right side -->
        <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img
            src=""
            alt=""
            style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: lightgreen"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```